# Use a Gem running on a different Ruby version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

What happens when I create a Gem and I specify in the Gemfile the ruby version?
Will applications running on different Ruby version be able to use my Gem?
For example with a Gemfile like this one

```
ruby '2.1.1'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Will an application running on Ruby 1.9 be able to use my Gem?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, Bundler will NOT stop you.
I created two folders containing two gems.

- ruby_new (a gem running on Ruby 2.0.0)
- ruby_old (a gem running on Ruby 1.9.3)

The Gemfile of **ruby_old** looks like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
```

The Gemfile of **ruby_new** looks like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem "ruby_old", :path => "/complete/path/to/ruby_old"
```

In other words **ruby_new** depends on **ruby_old**.
If I get into the **ruby_new** directory and I run **bundle install** this is what I see

```
bundle install
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.1)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using ruby_new (0.0.1) from source at .    
Using ruby_old (0.0.1) from source at /complete/path/to/ruby_old

Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Therefore the answer to my question is YES, it is possible for someone running on a newer version of Ruby to run my gem written with an old one.

The other way around is also possible. If **ruby_old** depends on **ruby_new** then running **bundle install** on **ruby_old** does not throw any error.